# Only print words that start with a specified letter out of a string in C language

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, printf

I need to write a function that will print words that start with specified letter inside a string.. my problem is that once i try to print a words, the function never stop.

Here is the code: (printWords is the functions, printWord is a helper)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char string[50];

void printWord(int *index, string sentence)
{
    while (sentence[*index] != ' ' || sentence[*index] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c", sentence[*index]);
        *index += 1;
    }   
}

void printWords(char letter, string sentence)
{
    int i = 0, *iPtr = &i;

    if (sentence[0] == letter || sentence[0] == letter + 32)
            printWord(iPtr, sentence);

    for (; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if ((sentence[i] == ' ' && sentence[i+1] == letter) || (sentence[i] == ' ' && sentence[i+1] == letter + 32))
            printWord(iPtr, sentence);
}

void main()
{
    char ex1_letter;
    int menu;
    string ex1_sentence;

    printf("\n\nPlease enter a string: ");
    gets(ex1_sentence);
    printf("\nPlease enter a letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &ex1_letter);
    printWords(ex1_letter, ex1_sentence);
}
```

The condition in the loop never seems to happen and i just don't know why..
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which loop, there are two?  And, why is `int i = 0` not in the `for`-loop?

Comment: The "while" loop in printWord.
i = 0 isn't in the loop in case the if outside the loop is true.

Comment: You only use `i` in the loop, so what you say makes no sense.

Comment: If you look, iPtr in `printWords` is set to the address of i. If the `if` statement is true, it calls `printWord` with iPtr (and thus i) as a parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main error is using `||` insted of `&&` in `printWord`. With `||` the condition will always be true since the character will always *not* be either space or the null character.

Some other points:

It's more portable for `main` to return an `int` (and have a `return 0;` at the end).

Use of `gets` is discouraged as it allows buffer overruns. `fgets` is more secure, but beware that it leaves the newline character at the end of the string.

Don't do things like `letter + 32`. Instead, use the functions in `ctype.h`. In this case, use `tolower` or `toupper`.

Instead of passing `i` as a pointer, just pass it as an `int` and return the changed value.

Don't use `printf` and `scanf` to print/scan a single character. Instead use `putchar` and `getchar`.

Use `++i` instead of `i += 1`.

Your `typedef` just obscures things. If the declaration of (e.g.) `printWords` is `void printWords(char letter, char *sentence)` then a C programmer knows what's going on right away without having to know what `string` is. The `typedef` really adds nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much, i used all of your tips and it now works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

In your `printWord` method:

```
while (sentence[*index] != ' ' || sentence[*index] != '\0')
```

This conditions will always be `true`. Change it to `&&`: print as long it is not a space AND not the end of string, like this:

```
while (sentence[*index] != ' ' && sentence[*index] != '\0')
```